# Incorrect integer value

Tags: c#, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to insert autonumber to my datagridview and save it to database but
I'm getting an error, incorrect integer value, Any idea how to fix this?

```
 int i =0
   int a = 0;

     string sqla = "insert  into tbl_visitor_form (Purpose,Date,VisitorNum)values('" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column11"].Value + "','" + Date + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column13"].Value + "')";
      cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqla, conn);
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
      {
       a = a + 1;
      dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column13"].Value = a;
      i = i + 1;
      }
```

Error occurs in ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: Thats not the correct way to compose SQL, use parameters, but if it is a DataGridView, if you research how the provider objects work, you dont need any of that code - they will do it for you - just update the DB from the DataAdapter.  Also, if "autonumber" means the PK , it is the job of the DB to provide it

Comment: Additionally to what Plutonix said, if you want to understand your present problem, i guess you have to take a long, stern look at how your composed(!) SQL query string actually _really_ looks like and probably how this compares to your database model (table definitions).

Comment: Yes i properly open an close my connection,  and my PK there is the VisitorNum.  Sorry.

Comment: show us the value of sqla. don't type it, copy paste it. im suspecting there is some extra space or tailing special char at the end

Comment: If `VistorNum` is the PK, you should not be passing a value at all - the unique identifier is the job of the database.  Ticks ( `'`) are not all purpose SQL delimieters - they force the value to text - a number is not text/string, a date is not text/string.  But again your tools will do all of that for you without data type errors and many other dangers if you let them

Comment: thanks for the comments, i already fix the problem in my code..